# Mac OS X 10.3 DMProxy -4231 error stopping Aqua bootup

Tags: macos

I have an old Apple iMac G4 (700MHz) which (sort of, right now) runs Mac OS X 10.3.9 (Panther).

The day before last it was working absolutely fine, booting up as always, but yesterday it just sat and gave me the Spinning Wheel of Death on bootup.

I used Open Firmware to boot into Verbose Mode and the system hangs at these errors:

```
DMProxy: theErr=-4231 [line 636, file DMProxy.c]
DMProxy: theErr=-4231 [line 722, file DMProxy.c]
```

I booted into Single-User Mode and ran Applejack, checked disk permissions, reset PRAM & NVRAM, etc to no avail.

Google didn't show up any cases of this error ever happening, either.

I don't believe I have a hardware issue as I can boot into Mac OS 9 fine (which is nice and all, but it's OS 9)

I'd really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this issue. :)

Do you believe the issue is fixable or should I just re-install? (This is not ideal as I do not have the discs - I bought the Mac second-hand with only power cable and speakers).